# Injecting values into form of website in android webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, kotlin

I have webview app where i load a website , this website has a registration form where i need to set values into those fields of form , i have written code which does that and data is being populated into fields , but the issue is that on website when i click submit button , it says enter your values ( firstName , lastName and so on ) , i could not really find why , i would appreciate some help on this topic , Thank you

- Code

```
        /// setting up webview 
  
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient());
        webView.loadUrl("https://xxxx/services/card- 
         reader/xxxxxxx");


  // INJECTING DATA
 private void fillFormFields() {

       String firstNameScript = "document.getElementsByName('firstname')[0].value = '" + stringArray[2] + "';";

       String lastNameScript = "document.getElementsByName('lastname')[0].value = '" + stringArray[4] + "';";

        String personalIdScript = "document.getElementsByName('personalId')[0].value = '" + stringArray[0] + "';";

        String birthDateScript = "document.getElementsByName('birthDate')[0].value = '" + getGregorianDate(stringArray[18]) + "';";

        String addressScript = "document.getElementsByName('address')[0].value = '" + stringArray[9] + " " + stringArray[10] + "';";


        webView.evaluateJavascript("javascript:(function(){" +
                firstNameScript +
                lastNameScript +
                personalIdScript +
                birthDateScript +
                addressScript +
                "})()",null);

    }
```